# Share posts to other user's wall in Sense/Net

Tags: sensenet

I am working on Sense/Net community edition. I need to share my posts to another user's wall but when using share command with the post, there are "My Wall" and "Current Workspace" options only. I can't browse other user's wall to choose. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the old webforms UI, when you click the *Share* link you should see a button at the end of the 'target wall' line in the pop-up dialog window (top rigth corner). That should open a content picker window that will let you browse to pretty much anything in the repo.

**Note**: the picker will open at different roots, depending on the currently chosen target - but you can always change the root of the tree by selecting it from the dropdown in the top left corner of the picker.

**Note2**: if you see the button, but the picker is empty, it is likely a permission problem: the user that you are currently logged in may lack some permissions on the target subtree.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @ Miklós Tóth! . I am in the case of your "Note2". Could you please help me in details about which permissions I have to get and which permissions of the user who will be shared my posts have to get in order to share posts between two of us?